# Open source web based video server app (in-house youtube)?

Tags: php, html, youtube, video-streaming, html5-video

I am looking for a web based video streaming server app.
I would like to get a kind of company in-house 'youtube'.
Required features:

- open source (PHP/JS preferred languages but It can also be java, python, ruby...)
- a web app with user UI
- expose services over a rich API
- HTML5 player, no flash required

After a few hours, I found solutions such as [Kaltura](https://github.com/kaltura/server) or [Ampache](https://github.com/ampache/ampache) but I would like to get others open source solutions.

Comment: Hm - not really an answer, therefore a comment: I am looking for a similar solution and thinking about developing this myself, using Amazon S3 services (EC2, S3, ElasticTranscode, ..). Just found https://www.phpsugar.com/phpmelody_demo.html which seems ok to me (though not open source) - did you already stumble over this?

Comment: hi @konrad_pe, thanks for your answer but I am looking for an open source software, phpsugar isn't.

Answer (score 0):

[youPHPTube](https://github.com/DanielnetoDotCom/YouPHPTube) is a good solution for those who are looking for a youtube clone.

The app is running fine and the project seems [currently active](https://github.com/DanielnetoDotCom/YouPHPTube/graphs/contributors?from=2017-04-02&to=2017-08-09&type=c).